# Debugging Missing $ Inserted after \printbibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a rather strange issue: After working on a new section in my thesis which includes text and `\autocite{}` citations. I got the following error:

```
2525: Missing $ inserted.
```

According to the TexStudio the error occurs on an empty line after `\printbibliography`

Note that removing `\printbibliography` resolves the error but not my problem ;)

I reckoned that the issue must lie in the newly added section and removed the entire section, corresponding entries in my `.bib` file and all auxiliary files, however this did not resolve the error.

Unfortunately, I don't think that I can include a relevant example from my code as my file is about 80 pages long and removing the edited section does not resolve my error.

Note: An updated PDF document gets generated despite the error.

**TL;DR & Question**

What is the recommended way to debug such a problem?

Alternatively:

If there are enough details, what could be the problem here?

Comment: you probably have in one of your bib entries something that is only allowed in math mode, e.g. an underscore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `test1.bib`

```
@misc{foo,
title={Something bad with _x},
author={me},
date={2024}
}

@misc{bar,
title={Something good},
author={me},
date={2024}
}
```

The document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test1.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah \cite{foo,bar}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces an error on the terminal and log:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12 \end
         {document}
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.12 \end
         {document}
?
```

which is a bit obscure, however you can tell tex to give more context by adding `\errorcontextlines=5` (you can get more but beware what you ask for).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test1.bib}

\begin{document}

Blah blah \cite{foo,bar}.

\errorcontextlines=5
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Now produces the error on the terminal and log:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
<argument> Something bad with _
                               x
\blx@theformat #1->#1
                     
<argument> ...{\csname abx@field@title\endcsname }
                                                  \blx@endunit 
\@secondoftwo #1#2->#2
                      
...
l.12 \end
         {document}
?
```

where the linebreak

```
<argument> Something bad with _
                               x
```

highlights the error occurs at `_`  and

```
<argument> \printfield [titlecase]{title}
```

shows it's in the title field of some entry.

From there you should be able to find the bad entry and change to

```
title={Something bad with \_x},
```

re-run biber and pdflatex, and the error will be gone.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear explanation including information about how I can debug similiar problems myself in the future! PS: It was just a single underscore in a title.